# How to use NODELET_DEBUG()

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably this is a stupid question, but I couldn't the answer in google or the ros wiki information about nodelets.

I'm using a launch file to launch a nodelet (in fact I've been using different nodelets) which is using NODELET_DEBUG(...) and NODELET_INFO(...) to output information. But in the console I only see the INFO output.

In http://www.ros.org/wiki/nodelet they say that "They also have the advantage that you can turn one specific nodelet into debug, instead of all nodelets of a specific type".

How can I see the DEBUG output? Is there a way to configure it in the launch file?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11931/how-to-use-nodelet_debug()/) by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2011-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, only `ROS_INFO()` level messages (and above) appear in the console output.

You can change that on a per-logger granularity by [setting the logger level](http://ros.org/wiki/rxconsole#Logger_Levels) in `rxconsole`.

There are also ways to set the [logger configuration](http://ros.org/wiki/rosconsole#Configuration) before a node starts running.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on 2011-11-16**:
Thank you, the rxconsoleloggerlevel is what I was looking for.